# How to create a n-series stacked plot with Matplotlib & Pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, stack

I would like to create a stack plot "Date" vs "Oil" for n-series "UniqueID" from a DataFrame

[image]

to get this graph

[image]

I hope my question is clear..

Jean

In the simple code below, where do I add the third variable "UniqueId" to draw the n series?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sp = ax.stackplot(df['Date'], df['Oil'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `y` parameter of `ax.stackplot` should be a list of `"Oil"` series for each `"UniqueID"` ([see the doc here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stackplot.html)). You can get such data with :

```py
y = [serie for uniqueid, serie in df.groupby("UniqueID")["Oil"]]
```

The final code should look like this:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = df["Date"].unique()
y = [serie for uniqueid, serie in df.groupby("UniqueID")["Oil"]]

ax.stackplot(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you 

I have this error message : TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

The problem seems to come from the groupby

Comment: @Jean.H Can you edit your question and add the result of `df.dtypes` please ?

Comment: UniqueID : object
Date : datetime64[ns]
Oil : float64
dtype : object

Comment: @Jean.H The groupby should work properly. I believe the error is coming from a higher level. Can you give me the error stacktrace ?

Comment: TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1560\2651865640.py in <module> 60 y = [serie for uniqueid, serie in df_filter.groupby("UniqueID")["Oil"]] 61 ---> 62 ax.stackplot(x, y)